# How to add and replace text from 6th character, starting from the back in excel

Tags: excel

I want to cut and replace the text starting from the 6th symbol (starting from the back) and replace it with "Overall"

> Applicant.Data.Consumer.ConsumerProfitValue
>
> Applciant.Data.Company.CompanyProfitValue
>
> =
>
> Applicant.Data.Consumer.OverallValue
>
> Applciant.Data.Company.OverallValue

etc...

Comment: the format of input is going to be same? ie XYZ.ABC.pqr.mnoValue; where you want to remove anything that comes between last "." and Value

Comment: As per forum rules, you need to show the efforts you've taken to solve the issue. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))))) & "Overall" & RIGHT(A1,5)
```

[image]

Comment: @Vityata  Now I understand

Comment: Yup, it is a bit of a golf to do it without VBA.

Comment: @Vityata Yes and thank you for your help understanding the question.

Comment: Welcome, Gary's Student :)

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want it do do:

```
var = "Applicant.Data.Consumer.ConsumerProfitValue"

var = Replace(var, "ConsumerProfit", "Overall")
```

Result = "Applicant.Data.Consumer.OverallValue", you can do the same with the other example of data..

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a high level joke ... But if it is, it really made me smile :)